# How to change tags with a namespace to tags with a prefix in the default namespace

Tags: php, regex, xml

I need to modify some XML tags by replacing the namespace colons with underscores so this:

```
<video:rating>5</video:rating>
<video:view_count>128</video:view_count>
<video:publication_date>2017-02-25T00:25:44+00:00</video:publication_date>
```

would become this:

```
<video_rating>5</video_rating>
<video_view_count>128</video_view_count>
<video_publication_date>2017-02-25T00:25:44+00:00</video_publication_date>
```

Notice that the colons in the date didn't change. I'm trying to create a regex that would grab any colon between "<" and ">" and replace it with "_" but I'm a regex noob so it's proving impossible :^)

Comment: What editor/RDBMS/OS/etc?

Comment: Oh yeah sorry I'm using PHP on Linux, editor is sublime text 3

Comment: Add those tags to your post

Comment: So you want to do this in PHP or in de editor?  PHP uses the PCRE regex engine, while sublime text uses their own custom regex engine, which is more limited than PCRE.

Comment: I need to do this in a php script

Comment: Stop vandalize the xml! A tag with colon contains a namespace prefix. Just learn how to work with namespaces.

Comment: Just a side note.  Have a look at [this old SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/4003419) and it's upvotes.  It's just that using regex to manipulate XML is often frowned upon. At least if when the programming language has better methods to [deal with XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/).

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Here's a PHP example snippet.

The regex only consumes the colon inside a tag, to replace it by an underscore.

```
<?php

$str = '<video:rating>5</video:rating>
<video:view_count>128</video:view_count>
<video:publication_date>2017-02-25T00:25:44+00:00</video:publication_date>';

$result = preg_replace('@</?\w+\K:(?=\w+>)@m', '_', $str);

echo '<br/><br/><strong>BEFORE</strong><br/>';
echo htmlentities($str);
echo '<br/><br/><strong>AFTER</strong><br/><br/>';
echo htmlentities($result);
```

You can test the regex [here on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/zMZCU1/1)

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I needed!

Comment: Just note that this regex doesn't account for tags with attributes like f.e. `<foo:bar type="42">`.  But with removing the lookahead `(?=\w+>)` it'll also catch the colon in those. Basically making the pattern more tolerant.

Answer (score 1):

It's a better practise to always use tools designed for XML when you have to deal with XML if you want to avoid unexpected results.

Let's say you have a sitemap file like this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
        xmlns:video="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-video/1.1">
  <url>
     <loc>http://example.com/video-page.html</loc>
     <video:video>            
        <video:thumbnail_loc>http://example.com/thumb1.jpg</video:thumbnail_loc>
        <video:title>Clown in the garden</video:title>
        <video:description>Crazy clown is riding a rabbit.</video:description>    
        <video:content_loc>http://www.example.com/video1.mp4</video:content_loc>
     </video:video>
  </url>
</urlset>
```

To change elements with the namespace "video" into elements in the default namespace with a local name starting with "video_", you can use XSLT (Extensible Stylesheet Language Transformations) to define templates in which you can edit elements of your xml document. These stylesheets use the xpath language to precisely target the elements you want.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
        xmlns:video="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-video/1.1">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="video:*">
        <xsl:element name="{concat('video_', local-name(.))}">
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that you need two templates: the first one (often called *identity* template) copies all your document and the second one only deals with tags from the "video" namespace.

Then all you have to do in your PHP code is to apply the XSLT to your XML document:

```
$xmldoc = new DOMDocument;
$xmldoc->load($sitemapFile);

$xsldoc = new DOMDocument;
$xsldoc->load($stylesheetFile);

$xsl = new XSLTProcessor();
$xsl->importStyleSheet($xsldoc);
echo $xsl->transformToXML($xmldoc);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, really useful info. I just needed a regex for a one-off dirty solution to extract some data so I accepted another solution. Will refer to this though in the future.

Comment: @Dioralop:  The solution you chose is a brittle, unprofessional hack.  Your goal of defeating XML namespaces itself is misguided.   You ought to at least chose a robust solution such as the one proposed here if you insist on thwarting namespaces rather than leveraging them as they're intended to be used.